# Jenkins installation on Kubernetes issue with volume conflict

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-cluster

I'm following this [Link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-jenkins-kubernetes) to setup Jenkins on Kubernetes cluster.

The environment information is mentioned below,

```
Environment:-

On-Premise Physical Server

# kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES      AGE     VERSION
master-server Ready    master     2d23h   v1.19.16
node-server1  Ready    worker1    2d23h   v1.19.16
node-server2  Ready    worker2    2d23h   v1.19.16
node-server3  Ready    worker3    2d23h   v1.19.16
```

I have below `yaml` files.

```
deploy-jenkins.yaml  
sa-jenkins.yaml  
service-jenkins.yaml  
volume-jenkins.yaml
```

`PersistentVolume` i want to use my `master` server local path, So in the `volume-jenkins.yaml` file I have updated `path` and `values` as below.

```yaml
  local:
    path: /home/linux-user/kubernetes/jenkins
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - master-server
```

When i apply the `yaml` files, My jenkins pod remain in `pending` status always.

Jenkins Pod status:-

```
# kubectl get pods -n jenkins
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-69b8564b9f-gm48n   0/1     Pending   0          102m
```

Jenkins Pod describe Status:-

```
# kubectl describe pod jenkins-69b8564b9f-gm48n -n jenkins

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  3m45s (x68 over 104m)  default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 3 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

PV describe details:-

```
# kubectl describe pv jenkins-pv -n jenkins

Name:              jenkins-pv
Labels:            type=local
Annotations:       <none>
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:      local-storage
Status:            Bound
Claim:             jenkins/jenkins-pvc
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          10Gi
Node Affinity:
  Required Terms:
    Term 0:        kubernetes.io/hostname in [master-server]
Message:
Source:
    Type:  LocalVolume (a persistent volume backed by local storage on a node)
    Path:  /home/linux-user/kubernetes/jenkins
Events:    <none>
```

What is wrong with my `yaml` files? and let me know the way to solve the node conflict issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...i want to use my master server local path`

Add `nodeSelector` and `tolerations` to your deployment spec:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        operator: Exists
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        ...
```